# Homeomorphic to $ [0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $f~:~[0,1] \to E$ continuous such that $f$ is not constant. 
Is it true that $f([0,1])$ contains a subset homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, $f([0,1])$ is even arc-wise connected. Section 31 of Willard's *General Topology*.